# Python executes a statement fine, but when run from freeradius modules/Rlm_python, the same statement fails the module

Tags: python, freeradius, stellar

Python executes a statement fine, but when run from freeradius modules/Rlm_python, the same statement fails the module.
The statement is:
`from stellar_base.address import Address`

There is no error codes or reasons to be found as to why it doesn't work, but I am guessing that anything to do with "stellar_base" would fail. So the ultimate question is **how to enable [stellar-base](https://pypi.org/project/stellar-base/) for execution from within freeradius module?** Is this possible?

When executed from Python environment, the same statement works fine.

Comment: Your python path is wrong

Comment: Thanks Arran! But would it not error execution of any python statement? Or maybe it's some special path you are talking about? Which path and where shall I check specifically? Thank you again!

Comment: Python statements execute fine. Modules do not import. Anybody there? Thank you!